# Angular controller not loaded in browser

Tags: angular, spring-boot

In our current project, we have developed microservices using spring boot. our web application is deployed in Unix box. We are facing a strange issue. Some of the JS files are there inside JAR file but when the application is getting loaded the old JS is loaded in the browser. We have tried incognito mode and also deleted all browser cache but still no luck. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It was not any issue with Jar file. There was caching enabled in CDN level. So the latest code was not getting effected. I chaged the cache mode to be development and it worked